# Javascript auto calculate time past 00:00 (midnight) in decimal format

Tags: javascript

I am trying to auto calculate time difference and it all works OK if time difference is on the same day example

starts ends  hours

08:00  12:00 4.0

problem:
22:00  01:00

gives for result -21.0 hours which is unacceptable
it should be 3.0 hours

Source code: [FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/L7h8w21w/6/)

```
<div class="container">
<table id="t1" class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Start Time</th>
            <th class="text-center">End Time</th>
            <th class="text-center">Stunden</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1" class="item">
            <td><input name="starts[]" class="starts form-control" ></td>
            <td><input name="ends[]" class="ends form-control" ></td>
            <td><input name="stunden[]" class="stunden form-control" readonly="readonly" ></td>
        </tr>
          <tr id="row2" class="item">
            <td><input name="starts[]" class="starts form-control" value="22:00"></td>
            <td><input name="ends[]" class="ends form-control" value="01:00"></td>
            <td><input name="stunden[]" class="stunden form-control" readonly="readonly" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').keyup(function(){

            var starts = $(this).find(".starts").val();
            var ends = $(this).find(".ends").val();
                        var stunden = NaN;
             s = starts.split(':');
             e = ends.split(':');

             min = e[1]-s[1];
             hour_carry = 0;
             if(min < 0){
                 min += 60;
                 hour_carry += 1;
             }
             hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
             min = ((min/60)*100).toString()

             if (hour < 0) {
                        hour += 24;
             }

             stunden = hour + "." + min.substring(0,2);



         if (!isNaN(e[1])){ //  && (hour > 0) && (hour < 24)
            $(this).find(".stunden").val(stunden);
                    }
    });    
});
```

Code Edited, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the solution because you use it for the minutes:

```
if(min < 0){
    min += 60;
    hour_carry += 1;
}
```

You have to do the same thing for hours:

```
if (hour < 0) {
    hour += 24;
}
```

Comment: Will this approach work if the second date is overflowing to the next month / year?

Comment: @marekful There are no dates here. Only hours and minutes.

Comment: Even though, the problem was related to a date overflowing to the next day. So definitely there aren't just hours and minutes, but at least days. And if you continue think ahead by the same line of logic, there are months and years, too. You just helped the OP to spot a problem in his already suboptimal code. If you can express the same logic in 3 loc rather than 30, that must be better.